# ngx-bootstrap dropdown not working in other modules

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular13

This question will pass me off as a newbie to angular even though I've been working with it for a long time. Do I want help with this problem. I am trying to use Ngx-Bootstrap dropdown, this works when I use it in AppModule, but when I try to use it in other modules of my app, this doesn't work. I'm trying to import this into other modules explaining in their sample codes, but this doesn't work. I have an application in angular 5 that uses this library in an outdated version and it works fine for me, but when I try to use it in Angula 13 with the latest version it doesn't work. I created a sample project with the same scenario but I have the same result.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fsjxn8

I have also tried to import the BsDropdownModule module in the new module but this causes the application not working.

Answer (score 0):

Update Auth module to

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, AuthRoutingModule, BsDropdownModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [MainComponent],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Remember to pay attention on the library of BsDropdownModule

from *import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/public_api'*;

to **import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown'**;

I've changed your project, if you want to check [see this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4s5ngu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth%2Fauth.module.ts)

It should work, have a nice coding!